# Not able to highlight code using angular-highlightjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, syntax-highlighting

I have the following code snippet in one of my angular js web application.

```
<div class="" ng-repeat="entry in fullSolutionPackage.solution.soln">
     <div>          
         <div ng-bind-html="sanitizeHtml(entry.solution)"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

The 'fullSolutionPackage.solution.soln' returns a json array, And the code is iterating through that array. Basically the array elements are something like the following:

```
<pre> 
   <code class="language-java"> 
        import java.util.Scanner; 

        class OddOrEven { 
            public static void main(String args[]) 
            { 
                int x; 
                System.out.println("Enter an integer to check if it is odd or even "); 
                Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
                x = in.nextInt(); 
                if ( x % 2 == 0 ) 
                     System.out.println("You entered an even number.");          else 
                     System.out.println("You entered an odd number."); 

             } 
          }

     </code>
  </pre> 
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
```

I want to use [angular-highlightjs](https://github.com/pc035860/angular-highlightjs) for highlighting the code. But I am not able to do this. The highlighting is not happening. I have tried the following:

```
<div hljs ng-bind-html="sanitizeHtml(entry.solution)"></div>
```

But it is not working.

Please help me find out the correct solution.

Comment: Are you having any particular problem with the documentation? What have you tried to do? In particular, have you tried adding 'hljs' directive on the second level `div`?

Comment: Yes I tried. But it didn't work.

Comment: Have you included `hljs` module as a dependency while creating your application module?

Comment: Yes I added all required files and dependencies in the app.js file.

Comment: Interesting. Any errors on the console? Can you reproduce the issue on http://plnkr.co/ ?

Comment: The problem is that hljs is not able to identify code that is dynamically loaded inside the <div> element. So I want to know a way how to make it identifiable. In plnkr.co - from  which rest api service can I load data that I use?

Comment: Did you try using [`hljs-source` directive](https://github.com/pc035860/angular-highlightjs#hljs-source-optional) instead of using `ng-bind-html`?

Comment: With hljs-source I am not able to use sanitizeHtml() method. Whatever raw data comes from json array, ng-source highlights that raw data. I am not able to sanitize that code.